# Storing JWT tokens on OAuth2 web client using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implementing an OAuth2 web application Client using Spring Boot 2.1.3 and Spring Security 5.1.3 that is obtaining JWT tokens from an authorization server through authorization code grant type and calls a protected resource server.

This is how the implementation looks up till now:

Security configuration and a restTemplate bean used to call the protected resource:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .oauth2Client()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor(clientService));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

The interceptor that adds the authorization header (from the framework's InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService) in the restTemplate:

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

    public AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
         Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String accessToken = null;
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            String clientRegistrationId = auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, auth.getName());
            accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        }
        return execution.execute(request, bytes);
    }
}
```

And the controller that calls the protected resource server:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${oauth.resourceServerBase}")
    private String resourceServerBase;

    @GetMapping
    public String getProfile(Model model) {
        Profile profile = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceServerBase + "/api/profile/", Profile.class).getBody();
        model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

The OAuth2 client configuration is directly in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          auth-server:
            client-id: webClient
            client-secret: clientSecret
            scope: read,write
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8081/client/login/oauth2/code/auth-server
        provider:
          auth-server:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth-server/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth-server/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8082/resource-server/users/info
            user-name-attribute: user_name
```

After doing some debugging I've observed that at the end of a successful authentication flow through OAuth2LoginAuthtenticationFilter the framework is storing the obtained access and refresh JWT tokens under OAuth2AuthorizedClient model in memory through the provided InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService.

I am trying to find out how to override this behaviour so that the tokens can remain available after a server restart. And also keep the user logged in based on this.

Should I just provide a custom OAuth2AuthorizedClientService implementation? How could I configure Spring Security to use it? And should this custom implementation store the tokens in a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

**Should I just provide a custom OAuth2AuthorizedClientService
implementation?**

I think yes, for solving your use case

**How could I configure Spring Security to use it?**

From [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#oauth2Client-client-registration-repo):

> If you would like to provide a custom implementation of
>   AuthorizationRequestRepository that stores the attributes of
>   OAuth2AuthorizationRequest in a Cookie, you may configure it as shown
>   in the following example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Client()
                .authorizationCodeGrant()
                    .authorizationRequestRepository(this.cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                    ...
    }

    private AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the case, as the documentation states AuthorizationRequestRepository is used to store the attributes of an OAuth2AuthorizationRequest which are clientId, redirectUri, scope and state. This is sent to the authorization server for an authorization code which is then sent in the form of an OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest to obtain the access and refresh token in a OAuth2AccessTokenResponse model. In the final step the framework saves the tokens in an OAuth2AuthorizedClient model using the InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService so this is part that I'm looking to override.